# Record audio from RTSP stream with LibVLC.NET

Tags: c#, wpf, audio, vlc, rtsp

I'm developing WPF application, that plays video from RTSP stream and try to record it to a file at the same time.

This is how it works:

I created LibVLC.NET.MediaPlayer instance and bound an event handler, that processed images:

```
_vlcPlayer = new LibVLC.NET.MediaPlayer(VLCLibrary, null);
_vlcPlayer.Display += VLC_Display;
```

VLC_Display writes each frame to WriteableBitmap, so it displays on ImageBox.
And then write it to a video file.

```
private void VLC_Display(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
         // write frame to bitmap
         VideoBuffer videoBuffer = _vlcPlayer.VideoBuffer;

         _vlcBufferBitmap.Lock();
         _vlcBufferBitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, (int)videoBuffer.Width, (int)videoBuffer.Height), videoBuffer.FrameBuffer, (int)videoBuffer.Stride, 0);
         _vlcBufferBitmap.Unlock();

         [...]

         // write frame to file
         using (var bitmap = MediaUtils.ConvertToBitmap(_imageBox.Source as BitmapSource))
            {
                     _aforge.AddFrame(bitmap, timestamp);
            }


         // ??? write sound ???

}
```

This works fine. The question is, how to write sounds?
I deсided to write sounds to a separate file, but I'm unable to find a way to read the audio stream.

I was trying to create a property in LibVLC.NET.MediaPlayer to handle sounds:

```
    private int length = 1024;
    public unsafe byte[] AudioBuffer
    {
        get
        {
            IntPtr mediaPointer = m_Library.libvlc_media_player_get_media(m_MediaPlayerHandle);
            if (mediaPointer == IntPtr.Zero)
                return null;

            try
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)mediaPointer.ToPointer(), length))
                {
                    byte[] audioBytes = new byte[length];
                    memoryStream.Read(audioBytes, 0, length);

                    return audioBytes;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                m_Library.libvlc_media_release(mediaPointer);
            }
        }
    }
```

But it does not return audio content.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.